# Trying to use useRef to run a function on a generated item in React/Remix/Prisma

Tags: javascript, reactjs, remix.run

I've gone through multiple useRef/useEffect instructions but I just can't seem to make it work here.

The code workflow here is: Remix/React, get data from database, display data, turn data into a ticker that can be updated

If anyone could point out any glaring errors they see in this code as to why the `useEffect` hook isn't firing, or why the `useRef` hook can never find the `{listRef}` within the `<ul>`, I would love to know.

```
import { Links, redirect, useLoaderData, Outlet } from 'remix'
import { db } from '~/utils/db.server'
import { getUser } from '~/utils/session.server'
import { ReactSortable } from "react-sortablejs"
import { useState, useRef, useEffect } from 'react'
import tickerStylesUrl from '~/styles/tickerDisplay.css'

export const links = () => [{ rel: 'stylesheet', href: tickerStylesUrl }]

export const loader = async ({ request, params }) => {
  
  const user = await getUser(request)
  const ticker = await db.ticker.findUnique({
    where: { id: params.tickerId },
    include: {
      headlines: true,
    },
  })
  if (!ticker) throw new Error('Ticker not found')

  const data = { ticker, user }
  return data
}

export const action = async ({ request, params }) => {

}
// The ticker function displays the items without styling, so it finds the database perfectly and can get the data
function displayTicker() {
  const { ticker, user } = useLoaderData()

  const headlines = ticker.headlines
  const tickerParentStyle = {
    width: "1920px",
    height: "1080px",
    position: "relative",
    backgroundColor: "black"
  }
  const tickerStyle = {
    position: "absolute",
    padding: "0",
    bottom: "0",
    color: `${ticker.fontColor}`,
    backgroundColor: `${ticker.backgroundColor}`,
    fontFamily: `${ticker.font}`,
    fontSize: "2em",
  }
  const tickerHeadlineStyle = {
    margin: "auto",
    height: "50%",
  }
  console.log("Headlines: " + headlines)
  // So begins the found ticker code I had hoped to integrate
  // Source: https://www.w3docs.com/tools/code-editor/2123
  function scrollTicker() {

    const marquee = listRef.current.querySelectorAll('.tickerHeadlines');
    let speed = 4;
    let lastScrollPos = 0;
    let timer;
    marquee.forEach(function (el) {
      const container = el.querySelector('.headlineItem');
      const content = el.querySelector('.headlineItem > *');
      //Get total width
      const elWidth = content.offsetWidth;
      //Duplicate content
      let clone = content.cloneNode(true);
      container.appendChild(clone);
      let progress = 1;
      function loop() {
        progress = progress - speed;
        if (progress <= elWidth * -1) {
          progress = 0;
        }
        container.style.transform = 'translateX(' + progress + 'px)';
        container.style.transform += 'skewX(' + speed * 0.4 + 'deg)';
        window.requestAnimationFrame(loop);
      }
      loop();
    });
    window.addEventListener('scroll', function () {
      const maxScrollValue = 12;
      const newScrollPos = window.scrollY;
      let scrollValue = newScrollPos - lastScrollPos;
      if (scrollValue > maxScrollValue) scrollValue = maxScrollValue;
      else if (scrollValue < -maxScrollValue) scrollValue = -maxScrollValue;
      speed = scrollValue;
      clearTimeout(timer);
      timer = setTimeout(handleSpeedClear, 10);
    });
    function handleSpeedClear() {
      speed = 4;
    }
  }

  const listRef = useRef()
  console.log("listRef: " + JSON.stringify(listRef))
  // This console appears everytime, but is always empty, presumably because DOM has just rendered

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("useEffect fired")
    // This console NEVER fires, sadly. I thought this would happen ONCE rendered
  }, [listRef]);

  return (
    <>
      <Links />
      <div style={tickerParentStyle}>
        <div style={tickerStyle}>
          <div key={ticker.id} style={tickerHeadlineStyle} class="tickerWrapper">
// HERE IS THE TARGET UL
            <ul className="tickerHeadlines" ref={listRef} style={{ margin: "10px 0 10px 0" }} >
              {/* Hoping to map through the ticker items here, and have them displayed in a list, which would then be manipulated by the useRef/useEffect hook */}
              {headlines.map((headline) => (
                <>
                  <li class="headlineItem" key={headline.id}>
                    <span>
                      {headline.content} {ticker.seperator}
                    </span>
                  </li>
                </>
              ))}
              {scrollTicker()}
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default displayTicker
```

As always, any help is appreciated.

Comment: When exactly do you want to the `useEffect` to be invoked?

Comment: Thanks for replying! It would be ideal if it could be invoked just after the data has rendered, so that the <li> elements actually exist. {headline.content} and {ticker.seperator} don't exist until the data arrives via {headlines.map} above.

Comment: Ok, I get it. So, what do you get when you try console logging `headlines` in `displayTicker`?

Comment: Currently 5 objects as [object Object]. Stringified, it is:

```
[{"id":"2e5513da-afbb-4bc3-af17-8e8e68854f8f","creatorId":"f6f336a9-9e9e-462b-a470-4ce52ece436b","content":"You shouldn't be looking here","tickerId":"93a1d0ec-b5a7-4d0e-8852-65b687de2bc1","position":1},{"id":"b4e3bfb2-fbae-4d1d-9905-0ae4a3be3a16","creatorId":"f6f336a9-9e9e-462b-a470-4ce52ece436b","content":"Twenty-five dead after nerf incident","tickerId":"93a1d0ec-b5a7-4d0e-8852-65b687de2bc1","position":2}]
```

Some removed for spacing

Comment: To explain also, I started going with the useEffect/Ref route as the marquee style code used "const marquee = document.querySelectorAll('.marquee');", which isn't recommended I believe in React

Comment: A few things that might help you: you need to capitalize you `displayTicker` otherwise it is not recognized by react as a custom component. You have written class instead of className twice. You need to put the key in your React.Fragment: `<></>` because it has to be in the element returned by your map (not its children). You might want to add `ticker` or `headlines` in the dependencies of `useEffect` instead of `listRef`.

Comment: Thank you, I'll get on to that now. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 4):

`useRef` is a hook that is used to access DOM elements, manipulating the DOM directly in a React application breaks the whole point of declarative programming. It is not at all advised to manipulate DOM directly using any dom objects and methods such as `document`. Coming to the `useEffect` hook, the `useEffect` hook runs conditionally depending on what's supplied in the dependency array, if none, the hook runs only once after the component finishes mounting. So you should be careful regarding what needs to be passed to the `useEffect` dependency array. Considering your case, when you pass `listRef`, the `useEffect` runs only when there is a change in the object and not it's properties, because objects are non-primitive, any changes in the property is not treated as a change in the object, and its merely an object property mutation that doesn't cause re-render. To steer clear, you should be sure of, when exactly you want it to be invoked, as you mentioned, you'd want it to run right after the data has rendered, you could instead use `headlines` in your dependency array.
Change the dependency array to include `headlines`.

```
 useEffect(() => {
    console.log("useEffect fired")
    // This console NEVER fires, sadly. I thought this would happen ONCE rendered
  }, [headlines]);
```

Alternatively, you could also leave it empty, making it run only once after the component has mounted.

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log("useEffect fired")
    // This console NEVER fires, sadly. I thought this would happen ONCE rendered
  }, []);
```

A caveat, the former snippet would run every time there's a change in `headlines`, and the latter would run only once no matter what changes.
So, depending on your use case, you might want to choose the one that best suits your needs.

Comment: Thank you for this, I appreciate it. However I am still getting this error:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'querySelectorAll' of undefined
    at `const marquee = listRef.current.querySelectorAll('.tickerHeadlines');` (./app\routes\generate\$tickerId\index.jsx:60:36)

It seems as though it breaks as listRef still isn't populated when it goes.

Also, the useEffect hook still doesn't fire, as that console.log never appears.

Comment: The `current` property on `listRef` holds the `HTMLUListElement` that furhter consists of the list items, so you won't be able to manipulate the DOM directly and is not advised also. Could you please prepare a minimum reproducible codesandbox  example for this code, so that it can help us get a clearer idea of what's going wrong, and be able to help you?

Comment: I'm sorry for the delay, I'll get started on that now.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things to code make code better:

1. initiate ref with 'null' value
2. call your 'scrollTicker' function inside useEffect Hook.
3. always remove listeners when component demount. Follow https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect for more details
4. you can use useEffect hook like this:

   useEffect(() => {
   // use your ref here.
   return () => {
   // Remove linteners

   };
   });